# How to predict weather?

Tags: prediction, forecasting

I want to know how does one predict day to day weathers. Like what are the factors that must be known to predict day to day weathers using a NN. Few factors I could think of are:

- Humidity
- Weather history
- Wind speed

What are some factors that a meteorology ignorant data scientist would require to correctly predict the weather?

Comment: Note: I know this question reflects lack of homework, but i needed a very quick answer from experienced people so I decided to ask it here

Comment: Problem is, this isn't a quick answer. Even today, different weather services predict different weather for the same region.

Comment: With great difficulty, it involves a lot of physics and differential equations.

Answer (score 1):

To ‘correctly’ predict the weather would require a clairvoyance that our best meteorologists have yet to divine.  In other words, they’re often quite wrong.

Weather prediction is very much a data limited problem. If you had access to each and every variable that contributes, you’d do a great job. The problem is one only has access to a subset, and the mechanics are still not fully understood. I’m not a meteorologist but I also suspect the sensors we have are sparse. I’d want temp, humidity, wind speed, and barometric pressure at 100 meter intervals both parallel and perpendicular to the earths surface, plus historical data, rate of change, ocean temp and currents, and the airspeed velocity of every unladen swallow in the area.

Comment: Hmm...I was just wanting to predict temperature and precipitation.. Surely that's possible?

Comment: Ironically, that’s what every meteorologist thinks when they wake up.

Answer (score 0):

[Here](https://stackabuse.com/using-machine-learning-to-predict-the-weather-part-1/) there is a great tutorial on how to do weather prediction using Neural Networks.

To reply to your question: Neural Networks are *cool* because they don't require what we call **feature engineering**, i.e decide what factors are important, because during training the algorithm would understand what is crucial for the task.

You have to understand the difference between [statistics, probability -> ML] and [physics, science -> meteorology]. In the first set, we use previous data to find the correlation between data, in the second, *they* use scientific knowledge like equation and theorem to find an answer.